automatic, explicit clearpage when heading is placed on a new page
i've read the answers here:
Avoiding page breaks shortly after section/subsection headings
and whilst this seems close to what i'm after, it's not exactly correct.
what i'd like is for latex to insert a \clearpage if the {sub,subsub}section/chapter is put on the top of a new page.
the reason i want this is because the ol'
\phantomsection
\section*
\addcontentsline
will result in the toc link preview pointing to the bottom of the previous page, and even though the jump isn't too bad, the mouseover/preview link in the toc entry is clearly not anchored right.
i thought the needspace or bottomtitlespacing option in titlesec would fix this, but i guess what i need is a way to explicitly insert a \clearpage when the processor is putting the heading at the top of a new page.

Have you tried using \section*{<stuff>}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{<stuff>} instead?

if you want unnumbered sections to make a table of contents entry it would seem better just to define them that way, rather than adding \phantomsection  in every instance. It's just a design choice in article class that unnumbered sections are not listed.

yes @skillmon i have tried that, but it didn't matter. it seems that when latex page breaks and there is a \phantomsection \section{} \addcontentsline, that the anchor in the toc preview will be at the bottom of the preceding page. it's weird.

@DavidCarlisle that seems like a good answer :P would this be the best way to do that?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77642053

why are you putting the phantomsection before teh section, that is forcing it on to the previous page

@DavidCarlisle it doesn't matter whether it's before or after in this case. i like the anchor above so i can see the title in the preview mouseover in toc

@davidcarlisle oh yeahhh i forgot about \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} :p

@davidcarlisle you should add your comment as the answer. tyvm master

@gagan the easiest way would be \newcounter{myscratch}\NewDocumentCommand\nonum{m O{#3} m}{\setcounter{myscratch}{\value{secnumdepth}}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}#1[#2]{#3}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{myscratch}}} and then use \nonum\section{<title>}.

no accept @Skillmon's he needs the points:-)

Also note that if you happen to use a KOMA class (though I doubt that since you tagged this [titlesec] and [titletoc]) you could use the macros \addsec and similar provided by KOMA.

The following defines a prefix \nonum you can put in front of sectioning commands to suppress their numbering while they still add their contents to the ToC, page header, etc.
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{myscratch}
\NewDocumentCommand\nonum{m O{#3} m}
  {%
    \setcounter{myscratch}{\value{secnumdepth}}%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}%
    #1[#2]{#3}%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{myscratch}}%
  }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}

\nonum\section{This is my section}

\section{Another section}
\end{document}


